# How to clear previous results when a search button is clicked? (HTML and JS)

Tags: javascript, html

A webpage created to fetch data from an api with a simple search bar and search button.

This is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search Games</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pbl.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br><h1 class="heading1">Gamer's DataBase</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
            <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search Game(s) by name..." id = "game_name">
               <button class="searchbtn" onclick = "movie_search();event.preventDefault()"><svg width="30" height="30" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="currentColor" d="m18.9 20.3l-5.6-5.6q-.75.6-1.725.95Q10.6 16 9.5 16q-2.725 0-4.612-1.887Q3 12.225 3 9.5q0-2.725 1.888-4.613Q6.775 3 9.5 3t4.613 1.887Q16 6.775 16 9.5q0 1.1-.35 2.075q-.35.975-.95 1.725l5.625 5.625q.275.275.275.675t-.3.7q-.275.275-.7.275q-.425 0-.7-.275ZM9.5 14q1.875 0 3.188-1.312Q14 11.375 14 9.5q0-1.875-1.312-3.188Q11.375 5 9.5 5Q7.625 5 6.312 6.312Q5 7.625 5 9.5q0 1.875 1.312 3.188Q7.625 14 9.5 14Z"/></svg></button>
    </div>
    <div class = "games"></div>
    <script src = "game(with css).js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
function movie_search()
{
var game_name = document.getElementById('game_name').value;
var raw = "search \""+game_name+"\"\;\r\nfields cover.url, name, url, screenshots.*; \r\n";

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.igdb.com/v4/games", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(gayme => {
        html += "<div class = 'gayme'>"
        let keys = Object.keys(gayme);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
        html += gayme[key]
        })
        html += "</div>"
        const game = `<ul><li><img src = "https:${gayme.cover.url}"><br><h4>Name:</h4><h3>${gayme.name}</h3><br><a href = "${gayme.url}">Click for Game Info</a><br><br></li></ul>`; 
        document.querySelector('.games').innerHTML += game; 
    
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
document.querySelector(".search").addEventListener("keyup",function(event){
  if(event.key == "Enter") {
      movie_search ();
  }
})
```

When I search something for the second time, the new resutls list below the previous results.
I want to add something to the code which will remove the previous results when the button is clicked and will display the new results only.
Please help.

Comment: As a side point, it is worth adding the attribute `type="button"` to your `<button>` element, this will remove the need for `event.preventDefault()`. The reason for this is that a `<button>` element `type` is "submit" by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you append the query results you have to clear the html of the search results:

```js
document.querySelector('.games').innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

For your quesiton,you just need to remove `+` when assign new value to elements `game`

So change

```
 document.querySelector('.games').innerHTML += game;
```

to

```
 document.querySelector('.games').innerHTML = game;
```

Note: according to your code,variable `html` seems not used

```
    html += "<div class = 'gayme'>"
    let keys = Object.keys(gayme);
    keys.forEach((key) => {
    html += gayme[key]
    })
    html += "</div>" // this variable is not used later
    const game = `<ul><li><img src = "https:${gayme.cover.url}"><br><h4>Name:</h4><h3>${gayme.name}</h3><br><a href = "${gayme.url}">Click for Game Info</a><br><br></li></ul>`; 
    document.querySelector('.games').innerHTML += game;
```

Comment: When I changed this particular code, I got the result of the search as only a single game and not a list of games. However, the clearing of the results on new search is working but it is not showing me all of the results.

Comment: Also, thank you for the "html" variable point. I'm new to web development, I didn't notice, Thank you.